# Unpack a Go map value in a Helm template

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I can't seem to find a simple and effective solution for what I imagine comes up a lot in Go templates / Helm.  Basically, given a values.yaml like this:

```
ingress:
  hosts:
  - host: busy-a.local
    paths:
    - backend:
        serviceName:busy-a
        servicePort: 80
      path: /busy/[A-Z0-9]{1}
```

and a templates/ingress.yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{.Values.project}}-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ .backend.serviceName }} # this works
              servicePort: {{ .backend.servicePort }} # but can we shorthand backend?
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

But, wouldn't it be easier to "unpack" the `backend` map in the `.paths range`, like `backend: {{.backend}}`?  However, it doesn't seem to work like that.

```
...
    paths:
      - path: /busy/[A-Z0-9]{3}
        backend: map[serviceName:busy-a servicePort:80]
```

What's the preferred way to unpack or assign a whole object like this in Go Templates or with Sprig extensions?

Comment: In general, there is no way for the template engine to figure out how to unpack that, with correct indentation etc. The engine looks up variable names and writes them as strings.

Comment: ah, good point and good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Helm has [a couple of barely-documented functions](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/engine/funcs.go#L50) and one of those is a `toYaml`.  This accepts an arbitrary object and writes it out in YAML format, unindented.

In your case you can achieve what you're trying for by combining `toYaml` and `indent`:

```
spec:
  ...
            backend:
{{ .backend | trim | indent 14 }}
{{/* above line intentionally at left margin */}}
```

Since `toYaml` can handle nested objects just fine, given your input and output, I might apply it higher up:

```
spec:
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths: {{- .paths | toYaml | trim | nindent 10 }}
  {{- end }}
```

`toYaml` will always emit a trailing newline, so I tend to `trim` it off so I get a little more control over it.  In the last example I use `nindent` to insert a *leading* newline to make the template a little bit more compact.